# creating a function in an iteration

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting

Ive come across some code that sorts a javascript array. Inside the sort callback, there is a helper function declared. Is it less performant to have this declared inside the sort? Is it more performant to make the helper outside of the sort and then used in the sort function?
before

```js
rows.sort((rowA, rowB) => {
  const getValue = row => {
    const sortValue = row.value;
    if (isNaN(sortValue)) {
      return sortValue.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      return sortValue;
    }
  };
  return getValue(rowA) < getValue(rowB) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

after

```js
const getValue = row => {
  const sortValue = row.value;
  if (isNaN(sortValue)) {
    return sortValue.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    return sortValue;
  }
};
rows.sort((rowA, rowB) => {
  return getValue(rowA) < getValue(rowB) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: are you sure about `sortValue()`? it should be a number, not a function ...

Comment: Corrected sortValue typo. it was a copy paste error

Comment: Another thing to consider besides raw speed is that declaring the helper function inside the sort callback scopes it to that block. That may be good, bad, or indifferent depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - it does not matter for 99% of use-cases.

Sorting takes `N log(N)` time, so any constant time complexity you add before running it does not affect complexity.

In detail - yes, it will be slower, because you need to put whole function into memory every single iteration.

In design - dont put any functions inside another functions unless you are javascript expert and you are 100% sure you want that.

Conclusion - there is almost no reason to put the function inside another function and there are several drawbacks if you do so, therefore dont do it.

Comment: That is not true, it does not allocate a new function at every iteration as the parameter of the sort function (i.e. your callback) is only defined once and then reused in a loop

Comment: @EliasFaraone - he is creating and storing new function dynamically into `getValue` variable. This will happen every single iteration.

Comment: You are absolutely right, sorry for the misunderstanding I haven't seen that sorry